# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource 4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have been trying to learn and implement Spring Security in my project but have been encountering this error.

```
Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception with message: class org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter and javax.servlet.Filter are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at com.yash.FlightReservation.FlightReservationApplication.main(FlightReservationApplication.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception with message: class org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter and javax.servlet.Filter are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter and javax.servlet.Filter are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterComparator.compare(FilterComparator.java:56)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1307)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.performBuild(HttpSecurity.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.performBuild(HttpSecurity.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:293)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

[This is the WebSecurityConfig File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTTCG.png)

[This class implements the UserDetailsService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohdhL.png)

Here are the dependencies that are being included for spring security:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I referred to similar questions also but none solve my error. This is my first program using Spring Security.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: please attach all the code correctly

Comment: Why are you using a 15 year old version of Spring Security? Do you use also Java 8? The current version of Spring Security is 6.1.0.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should not use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter cause it's deprecated and has been removed from spring security. Now, the best way is to define a bean of SecurityFilterChain. I advise you to follow this spring guide to define your own security configuration.

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Moreover, why didn't you use this depedency.

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```